# Material UI - DataGrid extend filter operators

Tags: reactjs, filter, datagrid, material-ui

I have a react/js/material-ui application. Where a DataGrid is used to show some data.

The filter option always has "contains, "equals", "startsWith", "endsWith", "isEmpty" and "isNotEmpty" options (that came from getGridStringOperators). But I would do like to extend it, adding 2 more option: "not contains" and "not equals".

Is it possible add the 2 new filter option to the getGridStringOperators?